# How to display the data starting from a common point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code I am displaying list of data in html, but data is not getting displayed in a proper format, adding the screenshot
How can i have it started from the same point

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
 datares = response;
 
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        text.innerHTML += "<a  href= " + datares.jsonData.data[i].uri + " target= _blank class= 'links'><span id='rank'>" + datares.jsonData.data[i].rank + ".&nbsp </span>" + " " + datares.jsonData.data[i].title + "</a><br>";
                    }
```

```css
#rank {
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #006ccc
        }

        a> span {
            display: inline-block;
            /* Remove parent's text-decoration */
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
         .links {
            color: black;
            float: left;
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 22px;
            font-size: 17px;
            width: 100%;
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: #006ccc
        }
```

[image: Screenshot of the issue, all the points after numbers are not begining from same point]

Comment: There should be some more code.  What is the HTML?  What does the JSON data look like?  What is the current format (that shown?) or what did the original format look like?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the rank and a non-breaking space

```
"<span id='rank'>" + datares.jsonData.data[i].rank + ".&nbsp </span>"
```

why don't you try using an ordered list instead

```
"<ol><li>" + datares.jsonData.data[i].title + "</li></ol>"
```

An ordered list will add the numbers for you.